# auto tools can not find boost (macOS)

Tags: macos, boost, autotools

I'm new to the Mac world, I just get my first Mac (coming from linux).

I try to compile a (quite big) school project that uses boost library. I have a given compile script using autotools but when I run `./configure`, it is not able to find boost headers:

```
checking for Boost headers version >= 1.61.0... no
configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.61.0
```

I installed boost (v1.78.0) using brew, but nothing changed. I checked in `/opt/homebrew/include` and I have the `boost` folder with headers inside but the configure script seems not able to find them.

I think I miss some sort of environment variable or something but I can not find any information about that.

The part of the configure.ac referring to boost is like that:

```
## ----------- ##
## Libraries.  ##
## ----------- ##

BOOST_REQUIRE([1.61])
BOOST_CONVERSION # boost::lexical_cast
BOOST_GRAPH
BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS
BOOST_STRING_ALGO
BOOST_SYSTEM
```

Comment: Does the `configure` script offer options for specifying where to look for Boost?  `./configure --help` should tell you.  In any case, `/opt/homebrew` is unlikely to be among the places it checks by default.

Comment: Oh ! Didn't know about that --help. Effectively there is a BOOST_ROOT environment variable that can be set to /opt/homebrew to let .configure know about boost location.
Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comment above, I found the trick: a BOOST_ROOT environment variable can be set to let configure know about boost location.